# Can I develop Windows Phone Apps on the BLU Win Jr and Android Apps in the BLU Studio C mini?

Tags: java, c#, android, windows-phone-8, mobile

Just wondering because I have an IOS device and wanted to buy this other 2 cheap phones to develop in the other two platforms and I am just asking to know if there is some restriccion or limitation that I might stumble uppon when developing using those devices.

UPDATE
Easy to close vote dudes, just provide a place where I can post the question right? Google didn't help here.

Comment: There are no restrictions for Windows Phone devices; you should be able to use the BLU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've talked to guys developing in android and windows phone. They state that what matters is the OS version on the phones. And the phones I put in the question are the latest in the market. So no problem to develop in those platforms